# binary representation of an integer

Tags: tables, programming, foreach

Is there a way to get a binary string of an integer calculated by e.g., `\pgfmathparse{pow(2,3)} \pgfmathresult` such that later on I can use the string digits in a foreach loop like .. if it is '1' do this or if the digit is '0' do that?

I don't need to use the tikz or pgf packages; if there is any other math engine with programming language features, that would be fine, too. My goal is to generate a table atuomatically.

Comment: perhaps using luatex is a better approach.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To store the binary representation of an integer in a macro you can use PGF/TikZ `\pgfmathdectobase`:

```
\pgfmathdectobase\yourresult{<integer>}{2}
```

In order to use this in a `\foreach` loop you would still need add commas between the bits.

Comment: Alternatively `\pgfmathbin{<integer>}´ or ´\pgfmathparse{bin(<integer>)}` (both store the result in `\pgfmathresult`).

Comment: I guess there is no function for converting the result into an array? Any idea how to iterate over the digits of a number (in base two)?

Answer (score 1):

The [bitset](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bitset) package by Heiko Oberdiek might also be helpful here.