# Graphics in LaTeX for bits representation within boxes

Tags: graphics

I use `\fbox{}` in LaTeX to draw a box around a text. How can one achieve a computer bit representation as shown below,

[image: Here the number of boxes must be the input and the data to be entered can be as text]

Comment: You should consider the [`bytefield` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/bytefield).

Comment: Apart from Werner's interesting suggestion (thanks! I wasn't aware of that package :D), there are lots of interesting solutions to similar problem in this [**question**](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110776/parsing-hexadecimal-numbers-to-binary-and-iterating-over-bits).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you should consider, `bytefield` package for such constructions. It offers many sophisticated layouts out of the box. For more details, type `texdoc bytefield` from the command line/prompt) or visit [texdoc.net](http://www.texdoc.net). An example (from th manual):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bytefield}
\begin{document}
  \begin{bytefield}[endianness=little,bitwidth=0.11111\linewidth]{8}
%\bitheader{0-7} \\
\bitbox{1}{Res} & \bitbox{1}{BE} & \bitbox{1}{CF}
& \bitbox{3}{$\mbox{Name\_Len}-1$} & \bitbox{2}{Len\_Len} \\
\end{bytefield}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

## Remarks

Using the almighty `tikz` I created a command `\drawbits`, which takes a comma separated list of values, where `0` denotes an unset bit and anything else (e.g. `1`) a set bit.

## Implementation

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}%for cropping
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\drawbits[1]{%
    \tikz[x=1.5ex,y=1.5ex,every path/.style={draw=black,semithick}]{%
        \foreach \y [count=\i] in {#1} {
            \expandafter\ifx\y0
                \draw (\i,0) rectangle (\i+1,1);
            \else
                \draw (\i,0) rectangle (\i+1,1);
                \filldraw[fill=black] (\i+0.2,0.2) rectangle (\i*1+0.8,0.8);
            \fi
        }%
    }%
}
\begin{document}
My bits: \drawbits{0,0,1,1,0,1,0}

\large My bits: \drawbits{0,0,1,1,0,1,0}

\Large My bits: \drawbits{0,0,1,1,0,1,0}

\LARGE My bits: \drawbits{0,0,1,1,0,1,0}
\end{document}
```

## Output

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the `bytefield` package is to use the venerable Tikz:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\drawbits[1]{\tikz\draw[step=12pt] (0,0) grid (#1*12pt,12pt);}
```

will load Tikz and define a command called `\drawbits` that will draw a specified number of bits.  For example:

```
Here are eight bits: \drawbits{8}.
```

produces: [image: output]